# How to add an existing Android Eclipse project to Google Code using Subversion?

Tags: android, eclipse, svn, subclipse, google-code

So, I have created an Android project in Eclipse and now I want to add it to a SVN repository on Google Code. I have created my Google Code repository (actually Eclipse Labs repository) here:
http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/missilecommand/source/checkout

Now I want to import my Android project. I have installed the Subclipse plugin and tested it works, which it does.

However, I cannot figure out how to import the project into the EclipseLabs repository. I can't use "Team->Share" as it tries to create a new repository, which I dont have permission to do (I assume you can only create new repos via the website?)

I tried checking out the blank repository trunk using subclipse: that worked, but then copying the source tree into the blank project lost all the Android specific project properties.

How do I get an initial import of an Android projcet into my SVN??!

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project -> Team -> share project[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK - I think I know what I was doing wrong:

I needed to import my project into the SVN trunk as a new folder in the trunk.
I thought I had to import it as a new folder under:
    https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/

which of course has already been created on the SVN server.

I have managed to import my project now via Tram->Share into the trunk of the SVN:
    https://svn.codespot.com/a/eclipselabs.org/missilecommand/trunk/MissileCommand

I think my misunderstanding means that I have named my repository poorly now!